# Scala : Is there a more concise way to compose the following higher kind method?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, tagless-final

UserRepository trait has two methods `isRegistered` and `insert`.

```scala
trait UserRepository[F[_]] {
  def insert(user: domain.User): F[Long]
  def isRegistered(user: domain.User): F[Boolean]
}
```

Boundary class is the boundary of the core application. For this example, it has only one method `register` which creates a new user only if it does not exist.

```scala
class Boundary[F[_]: Monad] private (userrepo: UserRepository[F]) {

  def registerUser(user: User): F[Either[UserAlreadyRegistered, Long]] =
    userrepo.isRegistered(user).flatMap {
      case true  =>
        UserAlreadyRegistered(user).asLeft[Long].pure[F]
      case false =>
        for {
          id <- userrepo.insert(user)
          errorOrId = id.asRight[UserAlreadyRegistered]
        } yield errorOrId
    }
}
```

My question is there a more concise way to implement `registerUser` method. I use cats core in the project.

Comment: Well the `for` can be replaced by a `map`, the `flatMap` body could be a `ifM` _(but I would never ever use that over pattern matching)_ - Not using typed errors may make this easier.

Comment: @nashter `UserRepository` is supposed to be a type class, isn't it? `class Boundary[F[_]: UserRepository : Monad]`

Comment: Yes @DmytroMitin `UserRepository` is a type class.

Answer (score 3):

As @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez suggested, you can use `ifM` function from the `cats.syntax.apply`:

```scala
import cats.Monad
import cats.syntax.apply._
import cats.syntax.applicativeError._
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.syntax.functor._

class Boundary[F[_]: Monad] private (userRepo: UserRepository[F]) {

  def registerUser(user: User): F[Either[UserAlreadyRegistered, Long]] =
    userRepo.isRegistered(user).ifM(
      UserAlreadyRegistered(user).raiseError[F, Long Either UserAlreadyRegistered],
      userRepo.insert(user).map(_.asRight[UserAlreadyRegistered])
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis Miguel Mejía & @Artem. Using a slight variation of the quoted answer. 

`userrepo.isRegistered(user).ifM(
        UserAlreadyRegistered(user).asLeft[Long].pure[F],
        userrepo.insert(user).map(_.asRight[UserAlreadyRegistered])
      )
`

Comment: @Artem The code doesn't compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/02BYUU5gR9mGmiMs3umbrQ/2 I guess correct version is https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/02BYUU5gR9mGmiMs3umbrQ/6 The context bound should be `ApplicativeError` or `MonadError` if you use `.raiseError`